# Synchronization on methods executing methods on other threads

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite, google-cloud-messaging

Hey m a newbie to android programming and I was working on this project. 
This question is pretty long so here's the deal.

I have this GCMIntentService class extending `GCMBaseIntentService` and whenever a message arrives from the server, the `GCMBroadcastReceiver` automatically recognizes it and calls the overriden `onMessage()` method in the GCMIntentService class. Now in the `onMessage` body, I am doing some operations on the `SQLiteDatabase` and I am notifying my adapter for list view by calling the `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` in the ui thread inside the onMessage body.

Now, if more than 2 or 3 gcm messages come simultaneously to the device the app crashes since more than one thread is calling the same `onMessage()` method and is messing up with my database and adapter as well. I figured I needed to use synchronized keyword on the method that should be used by only one thread at a time.

But since my `onMessage` method is an overriden method, I decided to make another method and put synchronized modifier on it but once again I need to call the `runOnUiThread()` method from inside it since i need to notify changes to my list view's adapter.

I just want to ask if doing this is the right way or is it possible to use a much simpler solution to my problem?

Here is the sample code to what m doing:

```
    @Override
protected void onMessage(Context arg0, Intent intent) {

// called when a new cloud message has been received
Log.w("Service ", "Started");
dbh = new DatabaseHandler(this);
sld = dbh.getWritableDatabase();
who = this;

// processing json object
putDataFromJSON();
//other stuff
}

synchronized private void putDataFromJSON(){
//do some work on JSON Object
//complete work on JSON by putting in database
dbh.saveInDB();
//notify the adapter
((MainActivity) MainActivity.con).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        //do other stuffs as well
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm writing a dummy code here that I think can demonstrate you an abstract architecture..

```
public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService{
private static ArrayList<Message> messageQueue = new ArrayList<Message>();
private static boolean isProcessingMessage = false;

onMessage(Context context, Intent intent)
{
 if(isProcessingMessage)
   {
    Message currentMsg = new Message();//Create a instance of message and put it in arrayList

   }
   else{
         isProcessingMessage = true;
          for(int i  = 0; i < messageQueue.size(); i++)
             {//  Process all your messages in the queue here
               messageQueue.remove(i);
              }
              isProcessingMessage = false;
       }
}

 private class Message{

//In this class you can configure your message that you are going to queue.
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the onMessage() method gets executed every single time a new GCM message arrives(even when you are not into your app, because we register this receiver inside the manifest file.) So, getting the context of your activity  my cause your app to crash (NullPointerException).

Now, as far as your question is concerned, you can maintain a queue that keeps track of incoming GCM messages. And, upon processing a message you can check for the entries in the queue and process them. For this purpose, you can use a boolean that  flags if any message is currently being processed (flag == true). And when (flag == false), you can take the next entry from the queue and process that..

I hope it was useful.

Comment: @Abhishek... how to implement the queue thing that you suggested? Pls show an example

Comment: also... if i can't get the context of my mainActivity, how else can i use the runOnUiThread Method?

Comment: @Sid, For this purpose, you can implement a listener in your activity.

Comment: Or, one more way is you can check if the returned activity is not null.

Comment: k m implementing it right now and will let you know if it did the trick

Comment: well it did the trick but m still facing another issue abt the main activity being null so the running on ui thread cannot be performed

Comment: also.. the listview complains abt

java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. [in ListView(16908298, class android.widget.ListView) with Adapter(class com.surv.ui123.lazy_adapter)]


For this, m updating the adapter and using list1.setAdapter(adapter); but it doesn't seem to work anyway

Comment: but the mainactivity is only null when the app is not in the backstack. ie. it isn't running in background